# Get page request data into google chrome exstension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, networking, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm making a Google Chrome extension that shows relevant data to what the user is looking at. Is there a way to get the urls or response of every request made on the network?

From what ive read, chrome.devtools.network only works when the console is open? This is what ive tried, but doesnt really do anything:

```
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function(result) {
var entries = result.entries;   
document.getElementById("prices").appendChild(document.createTextNode(entries));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this api in the google documentation. It has exactly what I wanted.

```
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html
```